# Why my file is closing before finishing executing my normal commands?

Tags: normal-mode

I have a file with random content like the following:

```
random content
random content
random content
```

If I execute the normal command with `:execute "g/./normal inewstring-"` I get the following result:

```
newstring-random content
newstring-random content
newstring-random content
```

This command is working exactly as I expected and there's no problem so far. However, if I try to execute `:execute "g/./normal inewstring-\<C-c>ZZ"` on the first original file, it will close the file before finishing the normal command, so if I open the file again to check its content I see the following:

```
newstring-random content
random content
random content
```

I don't understand why this is happening. In my view, the command `:execute "g/./normal inewstring-\<C-c>ZZ"` should work exactly like my first example, with the addition of saving and closing the file automatically. Am I missing something here? Why this command is not executing on all lines before closing the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're missing is that Vim will execute the whole command `normal inewstring-\<C-c>ZZ` for *each* line that matches the regexp. But the command ends with `ZZ`, which will save and quit. That's *part* of the normal command being executed by the `:global`. As such, Vim will execute it for the first line that matches, so the rest of the matches will not really get modified.

If you want to execute the `inewstring-` part for every line before executing the `ZZ` part, you can break it into two separate commands:

```
:execute "g/./normal inewstring-" | normal ZZ
```

Or, equivalently:

```
:execute "g/./normal inewstring-" | x
```

(The `:x` Ex command is the same as `ZZ`, see `:help ZZ` which mentions that explicitly.)

Comment: Tangential, but `:%s/^/newstring-/ | x`